# Subclassing a custom view that was created from a xib

Tags: swift, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I created a custom UICollectionViewCell (let's call it MyCustomCell) using a xib (MyCustomCell.xib) and I want to create a subclass of MyCustomCell (we'll call it MyCustomCell2). The parent of MyCustomCell2 (MyCustomCell) has an IBOutlet called titleLabel. However, titleLabel for MyCustomCell2 always returns nil even after I do

```
    self.collectionView.
            registerClass(MyCustomCell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier);
```

in viewDidLoad

and

```
    let cell = collectionView.
       dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell2;
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Any thoughts on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you use `registerClass` your outlets are not getting connected. You need to use `registerNib`.

Secondly, the outlets need to be connected in the xib which you are loading. If you are loading the xib of your subclass you need to connect outlets in it.

Comment: but MyCustomCell has a different cellIdentifier than MyCustomCell2, so wouldn't registerClass:cellReuseIdentifier cause a crash?

Comment: @user3808735 you need to use registerNib. And you need to register the nib in which outlets are connected